# OpenLayers - LayerSwitcher MattWalker not working with fetch()

Tags: openlayers, layer-switcher

I have a problem with Matt Walker's LayerSwitcher on my map construct. I use fetch () to get a WFS. Unfortunately, the LayerSwitcher does not respond to the vector and nothing is displayed in the switcher.
Has anyone had experience with this switcher?

```
fetch('[WFS-URL]').then(function(response) {
    return response.json().then(function(polygon) {...
```

Comment: That's not enough code to guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the layer to show up in the layer switcher it must first be added to the map as per https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html.

In addition you'll need to add a 'title' property to the layer, see the examples: https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher/blob/master/examples/layerswitcher.js#L46